# Celsius to Fahrenheit conversion in CSV file

Tags: python, csv, temperature

I want to take a CSV file with Temperatures in celsius and convert it to fahrenheit.

Current attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/temperature_data.csv', )

def f(x):
    x = x * 1.8 + 32
    return float(x)

df['AirTemperature'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

I am able to successfully do this if I simply input an integer into the function, but I keep getting this error message when I try to use the csv file:

```
can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

I've tried to convert values to float but I've had no luck.

Edit: 
The CSV file that I am using is multi column. It has more than simply air temp in it.

Also here is full traceback

```
`---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-a63269740c5c> in <module>()
----> 1 df['AirTemperature'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)

/Users/pvayn/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, args, **kwds)
   4040                     if reduce is None:
   4041                         reduce = True
-> 4042                     return self._apply_standard(f, axis, reduce=reduce)
   4043             else:
   4044                 return self._apply_broadcast(f, axis)

/Users/pvayn/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in _apply_standard(self, func, axis, ignore_failures, reduce)
   4136             try:
   4137                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
-> 4138                     results[i] = func(v)
   4139                     keys.append(v.name)
   4140             except Exception as e:

<ipython-input-3-895f5da25595> in f(x)
      1 def f(x):
----> 2     x = x*1.8 + 32
      3     return float(x)

/Users/pvayn/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.pyc in wrapper(left, right, name, na_op)
    647                 lvalues = lvalues.values
    648 
--> 649             return left._constructor(wrap_results(na_op(lvalues, rvalues)),
    650                                      index=left.index, name=left.name,
    651                                      dtype=dtype)

/Users/pvayn/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.pyc in na_op(x, y)
    588                 result = np.empty(len(x), dtype=x.dtype)
    589                 mask = notnull(x)
--> 590                 result[mask] = op(x[mask], y)
    591             else:
    592                 raise TypeError("{typ} cannot perform the operation "

TypeError: ("can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'", u'occurred at index 0')
```

Comment: The code you've given works for me, with a single-column CSV containing both floats and ints. Can we see the full traceback?

Comment: Seems pretty clear that `x` received by the function is a sequence type, not an int. This seems to be mentioned in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html You may need to modify `f` to accommodate that.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation for how I could approach that @DavidZemens?

Comment: Not really, never used Pandas before, but you could try `df['Air Temperature'] = df['Air Temperature'].apply(f)`? If `Air Temperature` is a series, then the `series` object also has an `apply` method.

Comment: That worked! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not used Pandas before but reviewing the documentation, this looks like it should work:

```
df['Air Temperature'] = df['Air Temperature'].apply(f)
```

`'Air Temperature'` is a series in the DataFrame, and the [series object](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#series) also has an apply method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code:

```py
df.assign(Fahrenheit = lambda x: (9/5)*x['Celsius']+32)
```

The formulas are :
Fahrenheit to Celsius formula:

*(°F – 32) x 5/9 = °C*  AND

Celsius to Fahrenheit formula:

*(°C × 9/5) + 32 = °F*

Answer (score -1):

f = 12
if I  want to convert f in Celsius to Fahrenheit I  tell you
the simple formula
day = f
days = day * 9/5 + 32
if I  print the days
result will be 53.6